# SQL Server how to change 1 letter from lower case into upper case?

Tags: sql-server, uppercase

I have column that contains many row. Each row has value about 3 words. I want to change first letter of that value into upper case. Only first letter, example abc def ghi into Abc def ghi. Please help me. Thank !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DONE !!
thx all

```
UPDATE table SET column= CONCAT(upper(LEFT(column, 1)), 
                         SUBSTRING(column, 2,100));
```

Comment: Replace SUBSTRING(column, 2,100)) by SUBSTRING(column,2,LEN(column)-1) because you have to measure the length only at runtime. Length of 100 cannot be fixed (:

Answer (score 4):

Since you only want only first character in caps, You can use `STUFF` with `UPPER` and `LEFT` like this

```
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(100) = 'abc def ghi'
SELECT STUFF(@Val,1,1,UPPER(LEFT(@Val,1)))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Abc def ghi
```

***Note:** If you have spaces at the start of the string use `LTRIM` before other operations*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT` and `RIGHT` in following:

```
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(100) = 'abc def ghi'
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(@val,1)) + RIGHT(@val, LEN(@val) -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(100) = 'abc def'
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(@val,1)) + SUBSTRING(@val,2,LEN(@val))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also this worked

```
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(20) = 'abc def ghi'
SELECT UPPER(SUBSTRING(@val,1,1))+SUBSTRING(@val,2,LEN(@val)-1)
```